# How to remember last visited items

Tags: php, arrays, session, queue

I have been experimenting with this code. $srv checks self address. So if we are in /_test.php?id=45 the code will execute. This is the code which is in header.php > header.php is included on every site.

```
if ( $srv == '/_test.php')
{   
    $aid = $_GET['id'];
    $numLastViewed = 5 ; 
    $lastViewedLocation = $_SESSION['lastViewed'];
    //check if first element of array exist
    if (isset($lastViewedLocation[0])) {
    //look for last set index
        for($i = 1;$i < $numLastViewed; ++$i){
            //when found > save it to var
            if(isset($lastViewedLocation[$i]))
            {
                $takenIndex = $i;                   
            }           
        }
        //check if array is full 
        if($takenIndex < $numLastViewed)
        {   //push element on end of array 
            array_push($lastViewedLocation, $aid);
            $_SESSION['lastViewed'] = $lastViewedLocation;
        }else
        {//delete first item and add current item to end of array
            $sub = array_shift($lastViewedLocation);
            array_push($lastViewedLocation, $aid);
            $_SESSION['lastViewed'] = $lastViewedLocation;
        }

    }else
    {   //if first element doesn't exist > save it to session
        array_push($lastViewedLocation, $aid);
        $_SESSION['lastViewed'] = $lastViewedLocation;  
    }       
}
```

After this I try to save session array to variable and print on screen in other file. With code below:

```
$lastViewedLocation = $_SESSION['lastViewed'];
            foreach($lastViewedLocation as $lastViewedAtt) {
            echo $lastViewedAtt;
            }
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: you haven't called `session_start()` anywhere, probably. you need that in EVERY script using $_SESSION...

Comment: oh i got that in beginning of every file.. and header is included to every file so it's also influences header

Comment: Then you should explain **HOW** this doesn't work?

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: Nothing echoes in start and nothing echoes when i visit few different ids

Comment: I suggest that you add some sort of 'logging' (var_dump is fine) in the the various 'logic paths') so that you can see what is happening and what values are being used when your code executes. e.g what values are in '$_SESSION['lastViewed']' in the various logic paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried checking my array with var_dump. It's said that it's NULL. So removed if clause in beginning so code will definitely execute so at least session will gets set with $aid on zero index. But it was still NULL.

Here i came to conclusion that $aid is not passed, so i took code from header.php to _test.php file, where the code actually worked. But i made some adjustment > the code didn't stop when array was populated with 5 elements. So i tweaked it a bit. Below is working version. Thank you all for your input.

```
                            if (isset($_SESSION['lastViewed'])) {
                                $lastViewedLocation = $_SESSION['lastViewed'];
                                $numLastViewed = 5;     
                                $takenIndex = count($lastViewedLocation);       
                                //check if array is full 
                                if($takenIndex < $numLastViewed)
                                {   //push element on end of array 
                                    array_push($lastViewedLocation, $aid);
                                    $_SESSION['lastViewed'] = $lastViewedLocation;
                                }else
                                {//delete first item and add current item to end of array
                                    $sub = array_shift($lastViewedLocation);
                                    array_push($lastViewedLocation, $aid);
                                    $_SESSION['lastViewed'] = $lastViewedLocation;
                                }

                            }else
                            {   //if first element doesn't exist > save it to session
                                $_SESSION['lastViewed']= array(0 => '$aid');

                            }
```

With this code array acts like queue with given limit. The elements came in queue one by one until number of elements in array reaches limit. Then the first element in queue is removed and new element is added to the end of queue. And this continue until session is destroyed.